# Accessing method on private Map member in Java

Tags: java, reflection, collections

I got this private member `private Map<Character, String> eTM = new HashMap<>();`.

I would like to be able read its size from a test. I'd like to do it using Java reflection, however it seems that in order to be able to call `size()` I'd have to get the field as a java.lang.reflect.Field. You can't call any Map methods on that so I'd have to cast the field to "Map<Character, String>" or "HashMap<Character, String>". That doesn't seem to be possible though.

I experimented a bit to see if you could somehow access the size method on a private Map, but I don't see a way to do this.
For example:

```
Field eTmF = Holder.class.getDeclaredField("eTM");
HashMap castTM = (HashMap<String, Character>) eTmF; //cannot cast
castTM.size();//not available
```

This shows zero length: `Holder.class.getDeclaredClasses().length;`

and unsurprisingly this has nothing to print:

```
Class<?>[] classes = Holder.class.getDeclaredClasses();
Arrays.stream(classes).forEach(c -> System.out.println(c.getSimpleName()));
```

Is this simply as far as reflection goes or is there a way?

For now I've loosened the field to "protected", but if it's possible I'd like to learn. For one thing I was hoping for hints on reflection libraries that may be able to go deeper.

Comment: `HashMap castTM = (HashMap<String, Character>) eTmF.get(myHolderInstanceToReadFieldOn)`

Comment: *I need to be able read its size from a test.* _Why_ do you "need" this? It's an internal implementation detail of the class. You should generally test _observable_ behavior, such as "the service only calls a downstream query a single time".

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I need that because I'm doing TDD and want to be able to verify the private method these are used in, before I've written the methods that are public. Because if I know this when I encounter problems implementing those public methods I know it's not a problem with the private one. That, and the fact I'd generally like to be able to if it's possible.

Comment: It is a good practice in TDD (and unit tests in general) to test your public interface. Testing private methods, the way you want, will be painfull and lead to difficult tests to write. If you really need to know the Map size, why not expose it with a package-private function?

Comment: As I explained @marcellorvalle I've already moved to "protected", which works in my context. I know it may be this issue indicates my design isn't up to snuff, but my tests have driven my development well. I'm also curious about reflection and keen to explore what is possible with it. When you know the rules you can break them if it's meaningful. At the very least I'm learning about the platform.

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k for the suggestion, but that gives me an IllegalAccessException when the field is private. For when the field isn't it works, but then I can forego reflection totally.

Comment: @MiB You need to call `eTmF.setAccessible(true)` before reading the field. Please find answers that give a complete snippet for reflectively reading fields.

Comment: My apologies @ernest_k, that's the peril of checking things before breakfast. I forgot to set it to accessible. What a palaver. Thank you again.

Comment: It’s not TDD if you start with *private* methods, as private methods are an artifact of a particular implementation, in other words, you have already defined (though perhaps not in written form) how the implementation ought to look like before you started writing tests. Do you see the contradiction. TDD implies defining the *contract* first, which implies public and perhaps protected members. Then, write tests for the contract, which implies atop these public and protected members only. The private members are off contract and should not be tested at all.

Comment: @ernest_k, you might want to add your first post as a proper answer, so you can be credited and others read an answer to my question.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your thoughtful suggestions. I'm going to reflect on my design process and analyze the reasons I want to get to private fields once this project is done. In one aspect this is a cosmetic issue as you can start or stay with package access and is only an issue when you'd like unit tests like these to be runnable also in later development stages.

Comment: @MiB I was not saying to change the visibility of the list but to create an acessor method to it's List::size() method.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding @marcellorvalle, but that would entail me to even further modify the class under test with the sole purpose to test it, which doesn't sit well with me. I'd regard that as worse than using reflection. With the solution from ernest_k I was able to set that field to private again. which means I won't later have to remove the failing test and my class is the way I wanted it. 
I do think I want to solve future design in a better way, as I think the suggestion to test the contract is key. That means I might have to design both test and class under test simultaneously.